# how to convert parts of a large list and divide up into smaller, simpler lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large list an example of this list would be:

```
list = ['1', '2', '3', 'x', '4', '5', '6', 'x', '7', '8', '9', 'x']
```

I am struggling to create separate lists from this total list value separated by the value 'x'.
So for example, I need the above list to be converted to this:

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3',]
list2 = ['4', '5', '6',]
list3 = ['7', '8', '9',]
```

Thank you for any help that you can give.

Comment: will these always be equal length lists?

Comment: will you have only 1 character per item?

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: No values in each item will always be different should have specified. The lengths of the lists can either be 2-4  in length but will always have an 'x' to separate the new lists I need to be separated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a temporary list to store the values between 'x' and then use a condition to find 'x' and load the list to your new set of list

```
my_list = ['1', '2', '3', 'x', '4', '5', '6', 'x', '7', '8', '9', 'x']
new_list = []

temp_list = []
for value in my_list :
    if value != 'x':
        temp_list.append(value)
    else:
        new_list.append(temp_list)
        temp_list = []

for sub_list in new_list:
    print(sub_list)
```

Results:

```
['1', '2', '3']
['4', '5', '6']
['7', '8', '9']
```

Just for fun here is a version using all kinds of fun methods but IMO harder to follow.

```
test_list = ['1', '2', '3', 'x', '4', '5', '6', 'x', '7', '8', '9', 'x']
idx_list = [idx + 1 for idx, val in enumerate(test_list) if val == 'x']
res = [test_list[i: j] for i, j in zip([0] + idx_list, idx_list +
       ([len(test_list)] if idx_list[-1] != len(test_list) else []))]

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Her'e a slightly more general version using `groupby` that will work for all iterables:

```
from itertools import groupby

def split(iterable, delimiter):
    return [list(v) for k, v in groupby(iterable, delimiter.__eq__) if not k]

l = ['1', '2', '3', 'x', '4', '5', '6', 'x', '7', '8', '9', 'x']
print(split(l, 'x'))
# [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this very efficiently by cleverly using strings. I convert the list to a string, so I can use the split function which splits it in sublists based on a part of the string. I than convert those back to lists and ignore the last empty one.

```
l = ['1', '2', '3', 'x', '4', '5', '6', 'x', '7', '8', '9', 'x']
s = "".join(l)
list1,list2,list3 = [list(substring) for substring in s.split('x')][:-1] #To skip the empty list from the trailing 'x'
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the downvote?

Comment: What happens if the things in the list are more than one character long?

Comment: It would indeed incorrectly put those as seperate elements of the end result. However, as it didn't occur in the testcase, I (and a lot of the newer answers) assumed all elements were of length 1.